# How to build a bundle sbt from source for offline use?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

My goal is to have a sbt jar file with all dependencies in order to create a debian package, so it could be install on machine without check/install package at first run.
Is it the right choice use [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) to build a sbt jar with all dependencies?

The sbt [binary version](http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html) doesn't come with dependecies and sbt download them at first run.

Comment: Not the answer you might looking for, but for an quick and dirty solution: Just copy the ivy cache (`~/.ivy2/cache`). If you explain why you try to accomplish this there is certainly a better solution.

Comment: @semptic I rephrase my question in order to explain my final goal. Thanks for your comment but for my case copying ivy cache is not the rigth "solution"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand your use case, but would [sbt-native-packager .deb format](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/) be a good fit?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is not exactly what I search but it will help me to packaging sbt dependencies. Thanks again